# WPF MVVM datagrid update property on change of another

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

I'm trying to create a datagrid for creating an work assignment list (AssignmentPlanItem class), which has comboboxes for Employee, Assignment and Workcenter (all separate classes and foreign keys of the AssignmentPlanItem. The plan is filled straight to the datagrid. I know this might be easier if adding items was done through a form, but I think this is a snappy method, and I don't want to change it.

After numerous days on this issue I have got everything else working, but I also have a DefaultAssignmentId as a property of the Employee class, and I would like the DefaultAssignment to be fetched automatically to the datagrid's assignment field when the employee is selected. This is my first WPF application, so it might be that my code works only by some miraculous chance, so feel free to give general hints. I feel I have tried every possible combination for the bindings, so now I have to ask for help, as I couldn't find anything with Google.

XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">

        <DataGrid x:Name="assignmentPlanItemsDataGrid" Margin="0,3,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridRows, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Employee" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path = DataContext.EmployeeComboRows, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"                                         
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedEmployee,Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding EmployeeId, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                      IsEditable="True"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="FullName">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Assignment" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AssignmentComboRows, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedAssignment,Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding AssignmentId, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      IsEditable="True"/>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>        
</Grid>
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class AssignmentPlanItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    DataContext context = new DataContext();

    //the datagrid collection
    private ObservableCollection<AssignmentPlanItem> _dataGridRows = new ObservableCollection<AssignmentPlanItem>();

    //datagrid selected item
    private AssignmentPlanItem _currentItem;

    //combobox itemssource collections
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeComboRows { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Assignment> AssignmentComboRows { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<WorkStation> WorkStationComboRows { get; set; }

    //the source event for the current assignment plan
    public Event CurrentEvent;

    public AssignmentPlanItemViewModel()
    {
        //populate combobox collections
        EmployeeComboRows = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(context.Employees);
        AssignmentComboRows = new ObservableCollection<Assignment>(context.Assignments);
        WorkStationComboRows = new ObservableCollection<WorkStation>(context.WorkStations);

        //getting the current event (yes, non-MVVM, I know)
        CurrentEvent = context.Events.Find(AssignmentPlanWindow.eventId);

        var planItems = CurrentEvent.AssignmentPlans.Last().AssignmentPlanItems;
        DataGridRows = new ObservableCollection<AssignmentPlanItem>(planItems);
    }

    public AssignmentPlanItem CurrentItem
    {
        get { return _currentItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentItem)
            {
                _currentItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
                OnPropertyChanged("DataGridRows");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AssignmentPlanItem> DataGridRows
    {
        get { return _dataGridRows; }
        set
        {
            _dataGridRows = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataGridRows");
        }
    }

    private Employee _selectedEmployee;
    public Employee SelectedEmployee
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedEmployee;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CurrentItem != null)
            {
                _selectedEmployee = value;
                if (_selectedEmployee != null)
                {
                    CurrentItem.EmployeeId = _selectedEmployee.Id;
                    var defaultAssigment = context.Assignments.Find((int)_selectedEmployee.DefaultAssignmentId);
                    CurrentItem.Assignment = defaultAssigment;
                    CurrentItem.AssignmentId = (int)_selectedEmployee.DefaultAssignmentId;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private Assignment _selectedAssignment;
    public Assignment SelectedAssignment
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedAssignment;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CurrentItem != null)
            {
                _selectedAssignment = value;
                if (_selectedAssignment != null)
                {
                    CurrentItem.AssignmentId = _selectedAssignment.Id;
                    CurrentItem.Assignment = _selectedAssignment;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So, I use the SelectedEmployee and SelectedAssignment properties to try to change the selected item of the datagrid (CurrentItem). The item is changed, but the change is not updated to the grid. When I save the grid, close and get back, the assignment has also changed.

In the XAML Assignment Combobox I tried

```
<SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.CurrentItem.AssignmentId, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

which actually got the view updating, but it changed all the assignment fields for all the rows in the datagrid to the same value as in the CurrentItem, even though I had `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=False` everywhere.

My model classes do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the `ViewModelBase` I ripped somewhere from the web.

So, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The specification of the column and rows in WPF is done by associated properties; hence on your `DataGrid` and other properties you can add the attributes of `Grid.Row="1"` `Grid.Column=:2"`... etc, So you don't have to have them be a child of  `<Grid Column="0">`.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean, but this is only a code snippet, so it might look a bit foolish. I left all the buttons out, which I have in a separate grid. Your comment might still be valid, but I have found it convenient to have these grids within grids as e.g. stackpanels have given me some problems. But I am very new to this XAML UI design also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many levels of `INotifyPropertyChange` which needs to be understood.

When assigning to a list type structure, the notify is only for when the *reference* to the list changes; aka a new list has been created. The notify event does not flag any changes to what is, or is not in the list, nor any individual items in the list which may have a property change.

An observable collection does send notifications on when an item in its list is added or removed, but not when an individual item in the list's property changes.

---

If you want an item's property to be reflected in the data grid after a change to its property, then that object instance must adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the property must call the PropertyChanged with its property name to be broadcasted.

What you most likely have is a DTO object which does not adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged` hence even though the current instance is properly referenced in your `Selected...` reference, the control that contains/displays the specific property value has no way of knowing the property has been changed; because it only monitors for a change event of that properties name.

---

What you need to do in your situation is create a `Partial` class off of your working classes and add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the partial and supply an override to properties with change calls (`PropertyChanged("FirstName`)` (or whatever your method call is)) which will need to show their change.

---

Though this doesn't speak to your direct situation, here is my blog article that does show how one can effectively use `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Its on a VM, but the same methods can be applied to your partial DTO object.

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a bit too abstract for my level, but I will try to look into the things you mentioned. Do you mean that the class with the property I want to change through the viewmodel (i.e. change Assignment with change in Employee) needs the partial class? Or many classes?

Comment: What I am saying is that you will need to add `INotifyPropertyChange` to your `Employee` class and adhere to the notification strategy as mentioned for the properties. If that class is generated, say from an ORM such as Entity Framework, then the modification of that class directly is not viable. In that case only, create an `Employee` partial class along side the `Employee` so you can have the overrides and call to notify but not mess with generated code.

Comment: OK, thanks. Yes, I'm using Entity Framework Code First, so I'll try modifying the Employee class.

Comment: Actually, the answer was just that I needed to make the `AssignmentPlanItem`inherit from `ViewModelBase` and attach the notification to ´AssignmentId`property there. So I'll mark this as the answer and post my now working code as an answer, once I clean it, and see what is superfluous. So, big thanks for your help, this also clarified a little about the general concept of whether the Model or the ViewModel should employ INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it working with the help of ΩmegaMan. The solution was to have AssignmentPlanItem inherit from ViewModelBase (i.e. implement INotifyPropertyChanged), and change the AssignmentId property from

```
public AssignmentId {get; set; }
```

to

```
private int _assignmentId;
public int AssignmentId
{
    get { return _assignmentId; }
    set
    {
        _assignmentId = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AssignmentId");
    }
}
```

The datagrid comboboxes had to have the following setup (not quite sure still if there is something superfluous):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="assignmentPlanItemsDataGrid" Margin="0,3,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridRows, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Employee" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path = DataContext.EmployeeComboRows, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"                                         
                              SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedEmployee,Mode=OneWayToSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding EmployeeId}"
                              SelectedValuePath="Id"
                              IsEditable="True"
                              DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Assignment" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AssignmentComboRows, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedAssignment,Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                              SelectedValuePath="Id"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding AssignmentId}"
                              IsEditable="True"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"/>
                </DataTemplate>

            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the `SelectedEmployee` in the ViewModel had the following code to change the Assignment:

```
private Employee _selectedEmployee;
public Employee SelectedEmployee
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedEmployee;
    }
    set
    {
        if (CurrentItem!= null)
        {
            _selectedEmployee = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
            if (SelectedEmployee != null)
            {
                CurrentItem.EmployeeId = SelectedEmployee.Id;
                var defaultAssigment = Context.Assignments.Find((int)SelectedEmployee.DefaultAssignmentId);
                CurrentItem.AssignmentId = (int)SelectedEmployee.DefaultAssignmentId;
                CurrentItem.Assignment = defaultAssigment;
            }
    }
}
```

There was still one tricky part, namely setting the ComboBox `SelectedItem` binding mode to `OneWayToSource`. Without this, all the comboboxes in the column would get the Assignment of the CurrentItem. So to my feeble understanding this means that the ComboBox  binding mode handles the updating to the ViewModel and Model, and the property change notification on the Model takes it back to the view through the `SelectedValue`. I'm still not sure whether it works or should work like this, but anyway it functions fully the way I want.